# Edges used in Shortest Path

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have just learnt "shortest path algorithm". Now I am wondering how the shortest path graphs looks like.

I.e. I am at Node `N` and I have run the shortest path algorithm from here. So if I make a Graph using edges used in the shortest path algorithm, how the graphs looks like?

I guess the graph will be Tree with Root at `N` with shortest path between Root to any other Node.

Comment: Yes you are right , the graph basically forms a tree (called spanning tree) with root N

Comment: I think your assumptions mostly hold. However things might get a bit more complicated for graphs with multiple paths with identical costs and even weirder for graphs with negative cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you see the sub-graph constructed from the shortest paths, yes, it will be a tree, in fact,  a spanning tree. It will have similar properties as well. see the links, I have posted.

> Given a connected, undirected graph G, a shortest-path tree rooted at
>   vertex v is a spanning tree T of G, such that the path distance from
>   root v to any other vertex u in T is the shortest path distance from v
>   to u in G.

References

> [shortest-path-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest-path_tree)
>
> [Spanning Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree).
>
> [shortest ptah tree.pdf](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~kmchao/tree10fall/spt.pdf)

Comment: Sure, but that's not an answer, that's just two links you dropped

Comment: @Rerito, He accepted my answer. If do not think this is not enough, could you please teach me how to do by answering in a better way.

Comment: If you had read [the answering etiquete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), you would have known that links to external resources must be contextualized. You must explain what they are about either by quoting important material or briefly explaining the concepts you want to link to. Sure your answer allows the OP to browse the concepts he is interested in (though elsewhere), but that does not make your answer good.

Comment: It's better but still needs improvements IMO. For instance, you don't recall what a spanning tree is. I am not among the people who downvoted you but I sure get why they did it in the first place. Hopefully these people will remove their vote if you improve your answer enough